# jQuery keyup event trouble in Opera

Tags: jquery, events, google-chrome, cross-browser, opera

I'm using some of hot keys in my website, site was tested only in Chrome and Firefox, and everything is alright there, but when I've tested site in Opera I found that many of my hotkeys are not working, after code checking found out that my function

```
$(document).bind('keyup', function(e){
  //....
});
```

is ignored by Opera, when I try to change it to

```
$(document).bind('keypress', function(e){
  //....
});
```

It started work correctly in Opera, but ignored by Chrome. Is there any cross-browser way out? Also I'm using jquery 1.5.1.

**upd.:** after changing `function(e)` to `function (event)` only arrown-down and esc. buttons still not working

Comment: Try this: $(document).bind('keyup', function(event){
//....
});

Comment: did you checked it with passing event in a function like this function(event)

Comment: yes, in my real code I'm using  "function(e){...}"

Comment: Check this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/cxV8D/ in all browser including Opera

Comment: Check this demo as well behaving different with function(e): http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/cxV8D/1/

Comment: I've found that like in this example http://jsfiddle.net/sfpQ8/  when I'm pressing up/down/esc buttons in Opera only button up is working

Comment: resolved by using 'keydown', function(event)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this:

```
$(document).bind('keyup', function(e){
  //....
});
```

See Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/cxV8D/1/

Try using this:

```
$(document).bind('keyup', function(event){
  //....
});
```

**See Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/cxV8D/

Comment: I've found that like in this example http://jsfiddle.net/sfpQ8/  when I'm pressing up/down/esc buttons in Opera only button up is working

Comment: even in your example button down-arrow is ignored by Opera

Comment: There is 0 logic in your solution

Answer (score 0):

There are similar issues with `keyup` in older browsers too.

Try using `keydown` instead of `keypress` or `keyup`.

It seems there are issues with special/control keys in Opera (Chromium builds) which fire only `keydown`.

Another issue is with <kbd>Esc</kbd> in inputs which fires `blur` instead of `keyup`, so you again have to bind to `keydown`.